# Body OnClick doesn't work... but the onclick works when attached to a <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have the following `Onclick` event:

```
onClick="document.body.style.background = 'url(galleries/g2.jpg)'"
```

and when I attach it to:

```
<a onClick="document.body.style.background = 'url(galleries/g2.jpg)'"> blah</a>
```

all works fine, but I want it as a body `onclick` event as follows:

```
<body class="g" onClick="document.body.style.background = 'url(galleries/g2.jpg)'">
```

and I get no dice.

The only thing to note would be that the class "g" already has a background image specified, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: maybe try `onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(galleries/g2.jpg)';return false;"` ?

Comment: how about `onclick="this.style.backgroundImage='url("galleries/g2.jpg")';"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.` like this

```
<body onClick="this.style.background = 'url(http://placehold.it/20x50)';">
```

JSFiddle of the code above [jsfiddle.net/mrRRG/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mrRRG/1/).
But please do not use this type of code construction. It's better to make few CSS classes and use javascript to change them on event fire

Comment: Doesn't work. Something else may be screwing me up. I think I'm just going to use a div with a bg image instead of the body. For some reason I think it's the body onclick that's giving me a weird response.

Comment: no, body onclick doesn't seem to work in the link you gave me... the text does... maybe this is a chrome issue?

Comment: @rootsup oh sorry wrong fiddle :/ wait a minute. The right one: http://jsfiddle.net/mrRRG/2/

Comment: that works on the fiddle, but even direct C/P it won't work on my site. I think it's cause I have the body class already asigned with this 
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url('galleries/george.jpg')center center fixed no-repeat; 
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }

Comment: @rootsup check Developer Tools Console or Resources for any errors on your site (especially 404 on `george.jpg`)

Comment: @rootsup add `height:100%` to `html` tag CSS: `html { height: 100% }`  to hide the scrollbars (on chrome they appear) set `body` margin to `0` ;)

Comment: Sigh. Thank you much!  Sorry about the trouble